# ConcurrentQueue(Of T) VS List(Of T) with Synclock statement in a multi-threading application

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, list

I have a `Public Shared queItems As Queue(Of String)` that it's used by many background threads whenever a thread wanted to remove and return the string at the beginning of the queue using `Dequeue`;

```
Public Function NextItem() As String
    Dim _item As String = Nothing
    SyncLock Form1.queItems
        If Form1.queItems.Count = 0 Then Return Nothing
        _item = Form1.queItems.Dequeue()
        Form1.queItems.Enqueue(_item)
    End SyncLock

    Return _item
End Function
```

I later got introduced to [`ConcurrentQueue(Of T) Class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) And I made the next version of `NextItem() As String` using `Public Shared queItems As ConcurrentQueue(Of String)` as shown here:

```
Public Function NextItem2() As String
    Dim _item As String = Nothing
here:
    If Form1.queItems.Count = 0 Then Return Nothing
    If Not Form1.queItems.TryDequeue(_item) Then
        Thread.Sleep(100)
        GoTo here
    End If

   Return _item
End Function
```

the first version is faster than the next version by around 20% in my machine.

But Are they equivalent when it comes to how thread-safe both they are ?

And which version is preferred to use ?

Comment: Your first version does not appear, to me, to be correct according to the remarks in [SyncLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t.aspx): "You cannot change the value of lockobject while executing a SyncLock block. The mechanism requires that the lock object remain unchanged." So it may not actually be doing what you intend.

Comment: that's weird. the first version is: NextItem() and the second version is NextItem2() . 

I do know this. however, if we want to compare both functions ( NextItem() and NextItem2() ). Which one should be used than the other in a multi-threading application ?

Comment: Well, seeing as `NextItem()` is incorrect (you should not use `Form1.queItem` as the lock object) and thus possibly *not* thread-safe, and `NextItem2()` uses `GoTo` rather than a while loop (using goto is generally regarded as being a bad construction in languages like VB), I suggest that you do not use either of them in their current form. If you look at the documentation you linked to, there is an example of using `.TryDequeue`.

Comment: your both methods are incorrect. `Sleep`, `goto`... are you kidding? Read this http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/02/10/c.net-little-wonders-the-concurrent-collections-1-of-3.aspx

Comment: @AndrewMorton you can't change the value being locked, but you can change the object that value points to. 

What's happening is that the Form1.queItem has a hidden field that indicates whether or not it is locked. `Synclock` sets that to true and `End Synclock` flips it back to false. You can still change other fields/properties on Form1.queItem without affecting the lock.

Comment: I am of mixed opinion about locking on `Form1.queItems`. Usually I prefer a private `SyncRoot As Object` field so I can easily see what's acquiring a lock and what isn't. But locking directly on the object that you are modifying is a fairly common practice and can be safely done. (Still, ConcurrentQueue is much safer and avoids this question.)

Comment: Oh, and not to be pendantic, but you shouldn't name your local variables `_item`. When people see an underscore, they think it is a field. So it's better to use `localVariable`, `_memberVariable` (or `m_memberVariable`), and s_SharedVariable`.

Comment: @JustCurious - Don't lock on `Form1.queItem` - it is a publicly accessible field so any code anywhere in your app that obtains a reference could obtain a lock on it and all of a sudden your code fails and you'll have a hell of a time working our why. You should only ever lock on a properly encapsulated object instance.

Comment: @JustCurious - I just realizes that `Form1.queItem` isn't your actual queue. Is that a typo or not? Either way, the comment about using a properly encapsulated object instance still applies.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, It was a typo, I just fixed it. I was using different names on my real code and changed the names here for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @JonathanAllen An underscore doesn't identify "a field". Underscores are typically used to identify at what top-level a variable was declared. A variable with one underscore could be declared at the top of a heavily-coded function/subroutine, whereas, a double underscore could be at the top of a class, a triple underscore leading to a base-class or a module.

Comment: In idiomatic C#, that is to say the way most C# developers write code, leading underscores are reserved for fields. Other languages may have their own informal standards, but that's how the C# community decided. We even have tools that enforce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the old queue, you usually do this (pseudocode)

```
Public class SyncQueue

    private _queue As new Queue(of String)
    private shared _lock As New Object() 

    Public Shared Function Dequeue() As String

        Dim item As String = Nothing
        SyncLock _lock
            If _queue.Count > 0 Then
                _queue.Dequeue(item)
            End If
            Return item
        End SyncLock
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub Enqueu(item as String)
        SyncLock _lock
            _queue.Enqueue(item)
        End SyncLock
    End Sub 

End Class
```

Whilst with `ConcurrentQueue(Of T)` all this taken care for you. And you should use `Try...` methods

```
If (queue.TryDequeue(item)) Then
    ' do something with the item    
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing to guess that the reason the second version is slower is that you are using it incorrectly. You don't need to check the Count if you are using TryDequeue, it takes care of that for you.

Fixing your code:

```
Public Function NextItem2() As String
    Dim _item As String
    Form1.queItems.TryDequeue(_item)
    Return _item
End Function
```

---

Reading the count from a ConcurrentQueue is actually very expensive.

When you add an item to a queue, it only has to look at one end of the queue. When you remove an item, it only looks at the other end. This means you can have one thread adding and another removing and they won't interfer with each other (unless maybe the queue is empty).

When you want the count, it actually has to look at both ends and count the items between. Which in turn requires either locking both ends, or continuously retrying until it gets a clean read. (You can examine the code yourself, but it's hard to understand.)

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs

---

This is literally the code they use for TryDequeue:

```
 public bool TryDequeue(out T result)
    {
        while (!IsEmpty)
        {
            Segment head = m_head;
            if (head.TryRemove(out result))
                return true;
            //since method IsEmpty spins, we don't need to spin in the while loop
        }
        result = default(T);
        return false;
    }
```

As you can see, it will set the result parameter to 0/null if the queue is empty. Hence the reason we don't need to explicitly check the function's return value.

Now if you wanted a different default, then you would write:

```
Public Function NextItem2() As String
    Dim _item As String
    If Not Form1.queItems.TryDequeue(_item) Then _item = [my default]
    Return _item
End Function
```

Comment: Your code is wrong. `TryDequeue` returns instantly with a `True` or `False` value indicating that it was or was not able to dequeue a value.

Comment: I don't care what TryDequeue returns. The variable _item will be set to nothing, which is by desired return value when the queue is empty.

Comment: But if `TryDequeue` couldn't return the item and gave me false, then do I just have to assume that the queue is empty ?

Comment: The code is wrong because the default value is not null. If you have a ConcurrentCollection<int>, and couldn't dequeue, you are left with 0, which could be a value. Hence why you do need to explicitely check the return value.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey `_item` is a `string`. Therefore `Form1.queItems` can't contain an `int`. Either it contains strings or you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: @JustCurious The only reason TryDeequeue will return false is if the queue is empty. So yea, you are safe.

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's a string or an integer. Default<string> == String.Empty, which could be a value, too.

Comment: No, the default of all reference types is null in C#. It would take you 2 seconds to verify that fact.

Comment: If the OP was posting about C# you would be right, however the default value of a string in VB is String.Empty. So in that case, it DOES matter.

Comment: It doesn't matter what he is using. ConcurrentQueue was written in C# so it follows C#'s rules. Serious, take 30 seconds to actually test this and you'll see that I'm right.

Comment: Did you try it out? I know you didn't. And your argument makes no sense. C# or VB, ConcurrentQueue is in the CLR. Default<string> in C# is null. In VB if you compare String.Empty with Nothing you get True. So the code above is NOT good if you are writing it in VB. Try it.

Comment: The original version returns nothing if the queue is empty as well. So no change there.

Comment: Also, it matters how you compare empty strings with Nothing. A value comparison is going to return true, but a reference comparison won't.

Answer (score 1):

The concurrent collections implements partitioning internally to avoid having to lock the collection. What that means is that in situation where there are many threads queuing and dequeuing (high contention), part of the collection can be "locked" while other parts (think of it like blocks of data) are still accessible. This is not possible using a simple SyncLock, because doing so locks the whole collection, preventing access from other threads. In situations where there are only a few threads involved, a SyncLock and list will likely be faster because you are bypassing the overhead of partitioning the collection. In situations where you have 8 or more threads all competing for the same collection a concurrent collection will most likely be orders of magnitude faster than list + synclock.

http://www.codethinked.com/net-40-and-system_collections_concurrent_concurrentqueue

EDIT: I in fact just tested this on my dual core machine using the following:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Private _lock As New Object

    Private _queue As New Queue(Of Integer)

    Private _concurrentQueue As New Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue(Of Integer)


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim sw As New Stopwatch()

        Dim lstResQueue As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim lstResConcurrent As New List(Of Integer)

        For i = 1 To 10
            Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf TestLockedQueue)

            sw.Start()
            t.Start()
            While t.IsAlive : Thread.Sleep(0) : End While
            sw.Stop()

            lstResQueue.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)

            sw.Reset()

            t = New Thread(AddressOf TestConcurrentQueue)

            sw.Start()
            t.Start()
            While t.IsAlive : Thread.Sleep(0) : End While
            sw.Stop()

            lstResConcurrent.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
        Next

        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Average over 10 runs: " & vbCrLf & _
                                      "Queue(Of Integer) with lock: {0}" & vbCrLf & _
                                      "ConcurrentQueue(Of Integer): {1}",
                                      lstResQueue.Average, lstResConcurrent.Average))
    End Sub


    Private Sub TestLockedQueue()
        Parallel.For(0, 5000000,
                     New ParallelOptions() With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 16},
                     Sub(i)
                         Dim a = 0

                         SyncLock _lock
                             Try
                                 _queue.Enqueue(i)
                             Catch ex As Exception
                             End Try
                         End SyncLock

                         SyncLock _lock
                             Try
                                 a = _queue.Dequeue()
                             Catch ex As Exception
                             End Try
                         End SyncLock

                         Dim b = a
                     End Sub)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TestConcurrentQueue()
        Parallel.For(0, 5000000,
                     New ParallelOptions() With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 16},
                     Sub(i)
                         Dim a = 0

                         Try
                             _concurrentQueue.Enqueue(i)
                         Catch ex As Exception
                         End Try

                         _concurrentQueue.TryDequeue(a)

                         Dim b = a
                     End Sub)
    End Sub

End Class
```

And the ConcurrentQueue is invariably twice as fast. It would be interesting to see the results on a more beefy 8-core processor. My results are 10 seconds versus 4.5 seconds. I am guessing the ConcurrentQueue won't scale well beyond 2 cores, while the ConcurrentBag will scale all the way up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to decipher your code. There are quite a few weird things going on.

In the first block you are accessing a `Shared` queue from your `Form1` class in an instance method called `NextItem()`. It isn't clear if `NextItem()` is defined in your `Form1` class or elsewhere. By this design it seems that you are anticipating multiple instances of `Form1` (or the class where `NextItem()` is defined) to all share the single queue. That's a little odd.

I'm going to assume that you can use an instance variable for your queue.

Also, you are enqueuing right after dequeuing. That also seems wrong.

So given that, this is what I think your first method should look like to be as thread-safe as possible:

```
Private _queItems As Queue(Of String)
Private _queItemsLock As New Object()

Public Function NextItem() As String
    SyncLock _queItemsLock
        If _queItems.Count = 0 Then
            Return _queItems.Dequeue()
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End SyncLock
End Function
```

In your second block of code you have a lot going on that makes it a bit confusing, but this is what I think it should look like:

```
Private _queItems As ConcurrentQueue(Of String)

Public Function NextItem2() As String
    Dim _item As String = Nothing
    If _queItems.TryDequeue(_item) Then
        Return _item
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Now, having said all that I think that there is a better choice for you than `Queue(Of T)` and `ConcurrentQueue(Of String)`. The class `BufferBlock(Of String)` (in the `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow` namespace) probably is easier to work with.

You could define this code:

```
Private _bufferBlock As New BufferBlock(Of String)()

'Blocking call, but immediately returns with value or `Nothing`
Public Function NextItem3() As String
    Dim _item As String = Nothing
    If _bufferBlock.TryReceive(_item) Then
        Return _item
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function

'Blocking call - waits for value to be available
Public Function NextItem4() As String
    Return _bufferBlock.Receive()
End Function

'Awaitable call
Public Async Function NextItem5() As Task(Of String)
    Return Await _bufferBlock.ReceiveAsync()
End Function
```

...and you could then use it like this:

```
Async Sub Main
    Dim t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(Function () NextItem4())
    Dim t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(Function () NextItem4())
    _bufferBlock.Post("Alpha")
    _bufferBlock.Post("Beta")
    _bufferBlock.Post("Gamma")
    _bufferBlock.Post("Delta")
    Dim x = Await NextItem5()
    Dim y = Await _bufferBlock.ReceiveAsync()
    Console.WriteLine(t1.Result)
    Console.WriteLine(t2.Result)
    Console.WriteLine(x)
    Console.WriteLine(y)
End Sub
```

...and this gives me:

```
Alpha
Beta
Gamma
Delta
```

NB: Sometimes the order of the results change as the asynchronous nature of this code means that `t1` & `t2` can come in any order.

Personally, I think that the ability to call `Await _bufferBlock.ReceiveAsync()` has the greatest potential to simplify your code.

At the end of the day I would look at whatever methods you come up with and time them properly to determine which is faster. We can time your code as we don't have it.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything else about what's happening, I'd suspect that the second one is slower because it's deliberately sleeping for 100ms. It's hard to tell from this how often that is happening. Take it out and try the test again. I bet that 20% difference will disappear.

If you're going to be simultaneously enqueing and dequeing then I'd use the `ConcurrentQueue`. That's exactly what it's for.